# How to switch x- and y-axes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there a simple way to switch the x- and y-axes, so that the x-axis becomes the vertical axis?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[domain=0:10]{1.2*0.000001*(0.2*(x*1000)^2 + 700*x*1000 + 25000)*2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of plotting `\addplot {<math expression>}`, you can use `\addplot ({<x math expression>},{<y math expression>})`, so in your case

```
\addplot+[domain=0:10] ({1.2*0.000001*(0.2*(x*1000)^2 + 700*x*1000 + 25000)*2},{x});
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[domain=0:10](1.2*0.000001*(0.2*(x*1000)^2 + 700*x*1000 + 25000)*2,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic! For a long time I have been searching for this answer. Thank you very much.